# When I use request.get() get the wrong answer

Tags: python, python-requests

I don't know too much about web. I only want to download all the zip files from a web page with a python script. But when I made the `request.get()` I only got a pre-page with code to load the real page (that is what I think). Is there any way to load the correct content?.
My pipe line overview is:

1. Load the page with `request.get()`,
2. Pass the info to Beautifulsoup4 to obtain all the urls to download.

The web page is [link](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

I could copy the html web info directly from the DOM, but, I really want to know what I'm doing wrong with the request command :(

```
page =requests.get('https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
soup.prettify()
print(soup)
```

What I got:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--

  Amazon S3 Bucket listing.


  Copyright (C) 2008 Francesco Pasqualini

      This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
      it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
      the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
      (at your option) any later version.

      This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
      but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
      MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
      GNU General Public License for more details.

      You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
      along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

  -->
<!--

  Modified by Nolan Lawson!  (http://nolanlawson.com).  I'm keeping the spirit of the
  GPL alive by issuing this with the same license!

  -->
<title>Bucket loading...</title>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
        .hide-while-loading {
          display:none;
        }
        .i-expand-collapse {
          opacity: 0.3;
        }
        .i-file-or-folder {
          margin-right: 4px;
        }
      </style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1 id="h1-title">Bucket loading...</h1>
<table class="hide-while-loading table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date Modified</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody-content">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script id="file-or-folder" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <tr>
      {{#if isFolder}}
        <td><i class="icon-chevron-down i-expand-collapse" style="margin-left:calc(({{numLevels}} - 1) * 16px)");></i><i class="icon-folder-open i-file-or-folder" style="margin-left:4px;"></i>
        {{simpleFilename}}</td>
      {{else}}
        <td><i class="icon-file i-file-or-folder"  style="margin-left:calc(({{numLevels}} * 16px) + 4px);"></i>
        <a href="{{url}}">{{simpleFilename}}</a></td>
      {{/if}}
      <td>{{friendlyLastModified}}</td>

      <td>{{friendlySizeName}}</td>
      <td>{{type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </script>
<script>
    (function($){
      "use strict";
      var FOLDER_PATTERN = new RegExp('_\\$folder\\$$');
      var TYPE_PATTERN = new RegExp('\\.([^\\.\\s]{1,10})$');
        var KB = 1024;
        var MB = 1000000;
        var GB = 1000000000;

    // replace last /index.html to get bucket root
      var bucketUrl = document.location.href.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '');
        var compiledTemplate;

    // return e.g. 1.2KB, 1.3MB, 2GB, etc.
      function toFriendlySizeName(size){
        if (size === 0) {
          return '';
        } else if (size < KB) {
          return size + ' B';
        } else if (size < MB) {
          return (size / KB).toFixed(0) + ' KB';
        } else if (size < GB) {
          return (size / MB).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }
        return (size / GB).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
      }


      // POJO describing a file or a folder
      function FileOrFolder(lastModified, etag, size, key){
        var self = this;

        self.lastModified = lastModified;
        self.etag = etag;
        self.size = size;
        self.key = key;

        // init logic
        self.isFolder = FOLDER_PATTERN.test(self.key);
        self.filename = self.isFolder ? self.key.replace(FOLDER_PATTERN,'') : self.key;
        self.url = bucketUrl + '/' + self.key;
        self.levels = self.filename.split('/');
        self.numLevels = self.levels.length;
        self.simpleFilename = self.levels[self.numLevels - 1];
        self.friendlySizeName = toFriendlySizeName(parseInt(self.size,10));
        var foundTypes = TYPE_PATTERN.exec(self.simpleFilename);
        self.type = self.isFolder ? 'Folder ' : (foundTypes ? (foundTypes[1].toUpperCase() + ' file') : 'Unknown');
        self.friendlyLastModified = moment(lastModified).format('MMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss a');
      }

        function onAjaxSuccess(xml) {
            var listBucketResult = $(xml).find('ListBucketResult');

            // set a reasonable title instead of "Bucket loading"
            var title = 'Index of bucket "' + listBucketResult.find('Name').text() + '"';
            document.title = title;
            $('#h1-title').text(title);

            var $tbodyContent = $('#tbody-content');

            // create the file or folder objects

            var filesOrFolders = [];

            listBucketResult.find('Contents').each(function(idx, element){

                var $element = $(element);

                var fileOrFolder = new FileOrFolder(
                     $element.find('LastModified').text(),
                     $element.find('ETag').text(),
                     $element.find('Size').text(),
                     $element.find('Key').text()
                );

                filesOrFolders.push(fileOrFolder);
            });

            // sort
            filesOrFolders.sort(function(left, right){
                if (left.levels === right.levels) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (left.levels < right.levels) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            });

            // fill in the rows
            var str = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < filesOrFolders.length; i ++) {
                str += compiledTemplate(filesOrFolders[i]);
            }
            $tbodyContent.append(str);
            $('.hide-while-loading').show();
        }

        $.ajax({
         url: bucketUrl,
         success: onAjaxSuccess
        });

    // compile while ajax is in progress
        compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#file-or-folder').html());

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a site which will be rendered via Javascript. Beautiful soup is not helpful here, because it requires a finished DOM. See e.g. this SO question for other approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049520/2648551

Comment: Thanks @colidyre with this context I can research more info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After read the discussion  provided by @colidyre.

I use `requests_html` library to request the get petition. This library download `chromium` web explorer to the pc when you use `render` method for first time. This method execute the javascript  in `chromium` to render the page completely.

This library has two version class for this endevour:

- syncronous
- asyncronous.

I had to use the async one. The syncronous version can be found in the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/).

This is simple and other methods implies to install a server but for me that was an overkill because this is not a frecuent operation to me.

```
# Libraries

from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
import requests

# Session and request

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
r = await asession.get('https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html')
await r.html.arender(sleep=1) # The sleep arg is necessary I don't know why...
r.close()

# Processing and saving to a file the links

links = r.html.links

dir_path = "data/"
path_file = dir_path + "url_files.txt" 

with  open(path_file, mode='w') as url_files:
    for link in links:
        if link.split('.')[-1] == 'zip':
            url_files.write(link + '\n')

# Download data

with open(path_file, mode='r') as url_file:
    for link in url_file:
        link = link[0:-1] # rid the \n character
        response = requests.get(link)
        file_name = link.split('/')[-1]
        with open(dir_path + file_name, mode='wb') as zipfile:
            zipfile.write(response.content)
        print(f'succcesful downloaded file: {file_name}')
```

Comment: Nice, that my comment helped you getting a solution. :)